# Radially unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, infinity, control-theory, lyapunov-functions

Example from Wikipedia.

$f(x)=(x_{1}-x_{2})^2$

Who can it bee shown that the function is not radially unbounded.

$l=lim_{x \to \infty}min_{||x||=r}[(x_{1}-x_{2})^2]$

by using $min_{||x||=r}$ as a step before taking the limit or done step by step.

who do you read $min||x||=r[f(x)]$ is it possible to check first $(x1,0)$, $(0,x2)$ and at the end $x1=x2$ $(x1,x1)$?

Comment: This screams "polar coordinates"; let $x_1=r\cos \phi$ and $x_2=r\sin \phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$ such that $||x||=r$ If $x_1=x_2$, then $(x_1-x_2)^2 =0.$ Hence

$$ \min_{||x||=r}[(x_{1}-x_{2})^2]=0.$$

This gives

$$l=0.$$